# Android SDK missing build.xml file - Ren'Py

Tags: python, android, xml, ant, renpy

I seem to be getting this error when trying to make an Android version of a visual novel made with Ren'Py:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\Users\user\Downloads\renpy-6.17.3-sdk\rapt\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:471: Invalid file: C:\Users\user\Downloads\renpy-6.17.3-sdk\rapt\android-sdk\extras\google\play_licensing\library\build.xml

I checked and I seem to be missing the build.xml file. What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by Ren'Py 6.17.4, which is now available from http://www.renpy.org/.

For the record, the problem was caused by an old version of the Android SDK being incompatible with a newer version of play licensing.